# What is '=>'? (C# Grammar Question)

Tags: c#, .net

I was watching a Silverlight tutorial video, and I came across an unfamiliar expression
in the example code.

what is => ?
what is its name? could you please provide me a link?
I couldn't search for it because they are special characters.

code:

```
        var ctx = new EventManagerDomainContext();
        ctx.Events.Add(newEvent);
        ctx.SubmitChanges((op) =>
        {
            if (!op.HasError)
            {
                NavigateToEditEvent(newEvent.EventID);
            }
        }, null);
```

Comment: It's a C# **lambda expression**. You can read all about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: if there's only one parameter on lambda, you can omit the parenthesis. `(op) =>` can be shortened to `op =>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> A lambda expression is an [anonymous function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) that you can use to create [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx) or [expression tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) types. By using lambda expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as arguments or returned as the value of function calls...

Huzzah!

Answer (score 14):

It's a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

If you're familiar with anonymous methods from C# 2, lambda expressions are mostly similar but more concise. So the code you've got could be written like this with an anonymous method:

```
var ctx = new EventManagerDomainContext();
ctx.Events.Add(newEvent);
ctx.SubmitChanges(delegate(Operation op)
{
    if (!op.HasError)
    {
        NavigateToEditEvent(newEvent.EventID);
    }
}, null);
```

Aspects of anonymous methods such as the behaviour of captured variables work the same way for lambda expressions. Lambda expressions and anonymous methods are collectively called *anonymous functions*.

There are a few differences, however:

- Lambda expressions can be converted into [*expression trees*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) as well as delegates.
- Lambda expressions have a number of shortcuts to make them more concise:

  - If the compiler can infer the parameter types, you don't need to specify them
  - If the body is a single statement, you don't need to put it in braces and you can omit the "return" part of a return statement
  - If you have a single parameter with an inferred type, you can miss out the brackets

  Putting these together, you get things like:

  ```
  IEnumerable<string> names = people.Select(person => person.Name);
  ```
- Lambda expressions *don't* support the "I don't care how many parameters there are" form of anonymous methods, e.g.

  ```
  EventHandler x = delegate { Console.WriteLine("I was called"); };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't search for it because they are special characters.

Sometimes the old-fashioned ways are the best. This worked for me:

- Start Visual Studio 2008 or later
- Hit F1
- Once the Help Document Explorer has come up, ensure the `Index` tab is selected in the left hand pane
- Enter `=>` in the Look for field
- The first item in the list is now the help article you need.